# Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'semantic-ui-css'

Tags: webpack, vue.js, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-css

I'm trying to use [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io) + [Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com/) but without success.
I tried...

1. `npm i  semantic-ui-css`
2. In my `index.js`.. `import semantic from 'semantic-ui-css'`
3. I add configuration into my `webpack.config.js`

   ```
   resolve: { 
         alias: {'semantic-ui': path.join(__dirname, "node_modules", "semantic-ui-css", semantic.min.js")
   }
   ```

But when I try to buid... error..

> ERROR in ./src/index.js Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module
>   'sematic-ui-css' in
>   /Users/ridermansb/Projects/boilerplate-projects/vue/src  @
>   ./src/index.js 15:20-45

Full [source here](https://gitlab.com/boilerplate-projects/vue/tree/webpack_semantic)

Comment: Are you transpiling your code? Have you tried using the babel loader for this? Instead of aliasing the library, you could just target it directly (Remove the alias and let webpack load the file automatically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do:

css: `import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.css';`

js: `import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.js';`

This solves my problem with webpack and react.

Answer (score 11):

If you came here trying to use 'semantic-ui-react' you need to install 'semantic-ui-css' seperatly to grab the css files:

```
yarn add semantic-ui-css
```

and then import it in the index.js

```
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
```

Answer (score 1):

To use 'semantic-ui-react' you need to install 'semantic-ui-css' `npm add semantic-ui-css`
then you need to import the css file into 'index.js' file.

```
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
```