# Remote: ! Precompiling assets failed. on heroku (Rails 6 and semantic-ui)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, webpack, semantic-ui, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to deploy my ruby on rails 6 application to heroku and I'm getting:

```
...
remote:        I, [2020-01-23T18:51:26.163296 #1627]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/public/assets/semantic-ui/brand-icons-42e369dc8c372973ba77a826b62d2c7a2070532313df832a23288ddb76974158.ttf
remote:        I, [2020-01-23T18:51:26.163727 #1627]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/public/assets/semantic-ui/brand-icons-42e369dc8c372973ba77a826b62d2c7a2070532313df832a23288ddb76974158.ttf.gz
remote:        I, [2020-01-23T18:51:26.164090 #1627]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/public/assets/semantic-ui/brand-icons-6519a15b08294be395ed914c40236ba604214cb1163b5311a9875f1df5eed86d.svg
remote:        I, [2020-01-23T18:51:26.164873 #1627]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/public/assets/semantic-ui/brand-icons-6519a15b08294be395ed914c40236ba604214cb1163b5311a9875f1df5eed86d.svg.gz
remote:        Compiling...
remote:        Compilation failed:
remote:        ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'semantic-ui-sass' in '/tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/app/javascript/packs'
remote:            at factory.create (/tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:925:10)
remote:            at factory (/tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:401:22)
remote:            at resolver (/tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21)
remote:            at asyncLib.parallel (/tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:224:22)
remote:            at /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2830:7
remote:            at /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:6877:13
remote:            at normalResolver.resolve (/tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:214:25)
remote:            at doResolve (/tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:213:14)
remote:            at hook.callAsync (/tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5)
remote:            at _fn0 (eval at create (/tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
remote:            at resolver.doResolve (/tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7)
remote:            at hook.callAsync (/tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5)
remote:            at _fn0 (eval at create (/tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
remote:            at hook.callAsync (/tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5)
remote:            at _fn0 (eval at create (/tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
remote:            at resolver.doResolve (/tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43)
remote:            at hook.callAsync (/tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5)
remote:            at _fn41 (eval at create (/tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:28:1)
remote:            at resolver.doResolve (/tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/ModuleKindPlugin.js:30:40)
remote:            at hook.callAsync (/tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5)
remote:            at _fn0 (eval at create (/tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
remote:            at hook.callAsync (/tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5)
remote:            at _fn1 (eval at create (/tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
remote:            at args (/tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/forEachBail.js:30:14)
remote:            at hook.callAsync (/tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5)
remote:            at _fn0 (eval at create (/tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
remote:            at resolver.doResolve (/tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7)
remote:            at hook.callAsync (/tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5)
remote:            at _fn0 (eval at create (/tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
remote:            at hook.callAsync (/tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5)
remote:            at _fn0 (eval at create (/tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
remote:            at resolver.doResolve (/tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43)
remote:            at hook.callAsync (/tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5)
remote:            at _fn42 (eval at create (/tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
remote:            at hook.callAsync (/tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5)
remote:            at _fn0 (eval at create (/tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
remote:        resolve 'semantic-ui-sass' in '/tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/app/javascript/packs'
remote:          Parsed request is a module
remote:          using description file: /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript/packs)
remote:            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:            resolve as module
remote:              looking for modules in /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/app/javascript
remote:                using description file: /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript)
remote:                  Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                  using description file: /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript/semantic-ui-sass)
remote:                    no extension
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/app/javascript/semantic-ui-sass doesn't exist
remote:                    .mjs
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/app/javascript/semantic-ui-sass.mjs doesn't exist
remote:                    .js
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/app/javascript/semantic-ui-sass.js doesn't exist
remote:                    .sass
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/app/javascript/semantic-ui-sass.sass doesn't exist
remote:                    .scss
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/app/javascript/semantic-ui-sass.scss doesn't exist
remote:                    .css
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/app/javascript/semantic-ui-sass.css doesn't exist
remote:                    .module.sass
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/app/javascript/semantic-ui-sass.module.sass doesn't exist
remote:                    .module.scss
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/app/javascript/semantic-ui-sass.module.scss doesn't exist
remote:                    .module.css
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/app/javascript/semantic-ui-sass.module.css doesn't exist
remote:                    .png
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/app/javascript/semantic-ui-sass.png doesn't exist
remote:                    .svg
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/app/javascript/semantic-ui-sass.svg doesn't exist
remote:                    .gif
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/app/javascript/semantic-ui-sass.gif doesn't exist
remote:                    .jpeg
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/app/javascript/semantic-ui-sass.jpeg doesn't exist
remote:                    .jpg
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/app/javascript/semantic-ui-sass.jpg doesn't exist
remote:                    as directory
remote:                      /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/app/javascript/semantic-ui-sass doesn't exist
remote:              /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/app/javascript/packs/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
remote:              /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/app/javascript/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
remote:              /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/app/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
remote:              /tmp/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
remote:              /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
remote:              looking for modules in /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules
remote:                using description file: /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
remote:                  Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                  using description file: /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/semantic-ui-sass)
remote:                    no extension
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/semantic-ui-sass doesn't exist
remote:                    .mjs
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/semantic-ui-sass.mjs doesn't exist
remote:                    .js
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/semantic-ui-sass.js doesn't exist
remote:                    .sass
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/semantic-ui-sass.sass doesn't exist
remote:                    .scss
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/semantic-ui-sass.scss doesn't exist
remote:                    .css
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/semantic-ui-sass.css doesn't exist
remote:                    .module.sass
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/semantic-ui-sass.module.sass doesn't exist
remote:                    .module.scss
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/semantic-ui-sass.module.scss doesn't exist
remote:                    .module.css
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/semantic-ui-sass.module.css doesn't exist
remote:                    .png
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/semantic-ui-sass.png doesn't exist
remote:                    .svg
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/semantic-ui-sass.svg doesn't exist
remote:                    .gif
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/semantic-ui-sass.gif doesn't exist
remote:                    .jpeg
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/semantic-ui-sass.jpeg doesn't exist
remote:                    .jpg
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/semantic-ui-sass.jpg doesn't exist
remote:                    as directory
remote:                      /tmp/build_f6fcbd9561d1b9a0ac9f0eb2c4fc1207/node_modules/semantic-ui-sass doesn't exist
remote:        
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
```

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19650621/heroku-upload-precompiling-assets-failed) when I do this:

```
# config/application.rb
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

The error stays. And I made [this](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/530)

```
NODE_ENV=production RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile --trace
```

All works fine in local but if I open locally the styles aren't there and if I deploy to heroku the same error stays.
And also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56254064/1418118)
but still get the same error.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm trying to deploy a new rails 6 project to heroku and running into this as well

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this when deploying my Rails6 + Semantic UI app to Heroku as well -- posting my solution in case this helps future people:

This was happening due to SemanticUI being misconfigured. My `app/javascript/packs/application.js` had this:

`require("semantic-ui")`

instead of:

`//= require("semantic-ui")`

After fixing this line my app was able to properly build and deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `package.json`

I just had the same error and found that my *`semantic-ui-sass`* package was in the `devdependecies` section and thus was not being installed in the production environment.

```sh
$ yarn remove semantic-ui-sass

$ yarn add semantic-ui-sass --prod
```